# How to get my <td> act like <tr>

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a table responsive and I need the  responsive and stack within each other like a table row

**Html**

```
<html >
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teststyles.css"> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<table> 
<tr>  
    <td> 
        <p> Stuff </p>
    </td> 
    <td > 
        <p> Stuff </p>
     </td> 
    <td > 
        <p> Stuff </p>
    </td>  
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    width: 990px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
 }
td{
    display:table-row;
    background:#efefef;
 }
```

So I thought table-row makes an element behave as table row but for some reason its not stacking like one. Any ideas or tips?

EDIT: [image]

Looks like this when I open it on regular html but when I open it on fiddle it's great

Comment: A table might not be the best choice for this.

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code and it seems to work alright for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BJLrT/ Are you expecting a different result?

Comment: yeah I'm forced to use a table, this is for company and I have to use the code they gave, this is my test code to understand how to go about it

Comment: @nullability yeah it works on my fiddle but won't work on my actual html

Comment: Maybe something is overriding your styles?

Comment: @nullability nothing is overriding it, I took out the other CSS's and meta tag to be sure

Comment: Please tell me the data is actually tabular and the tables aren't for formatting...

Comment: @user2809321, if something works when isolated, but doesn't work when implemented.  There is something wrong with the implementation.  Nobody here will be able to fix what isn't broken.

Comment: You can try to kill display using float *and clear*: http://jsfiddle.net/56sWL/show http://jsfiddle.net/56sWL/ Make sure you use a valid doctype. <html> by itself is not

Comment: @GCyrillus yeah it was a simple mistake, forgot to add a doctype... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a doctype in your HTML file. The first line should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```